# Load images in the same order as the files

Tags: jquery, foreach, each, firebase-storage

I am working with Firebase Storage. In a bucket I have several image files and a listfile.txt with the list of all files.
What I need to do is to load the images and put them into an array in the same order as the files are listed in `listfile.txt`.

I am facing issues, as getDownloadURL() is asynchronous and the images are loaded in a random order into the `overlay` Array.

```
var files=[];
var mapRef=[];
var overlay=[];

var listMapsRef = storageRef.child(prefix+"/listfile.txt");
listMapsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    $.get(url, function(txt){
        files = txt.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            mapRef.push(storageRef.child(files[i]));
            .....
            .....
        }
        count = mapRef.length;
        mapRef.forEach(function(oneMap) {
                oneMap.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                ovl=loadImage(url);
                overlay.push(ovl);
                if (!--count) {
                    startMyApp();
                    }
                });
            });

    }); //.get
});  //.then
```

Comment: As the requests are asynchronous there's no way to order their responses (apart from using synchronous requests, but that's not a workable solution). Instead, once all requests have been received, you could re-order the resulting array to match the required order.

Comment: You're right. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this pseudo-code

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promsie((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, (data, err) => {
       if (err) reject(err);
       else resolve(data);
    })
  });
}

const overlay = await Promise.all(
    mapRef.map(
        oneMap => oneMap
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => loadImage(url)
    )
);
```